# MSTest does not read config item on Jenkins

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jenkins, mstest

I have a normal Web Api 2 project and a MS unit test project to test it.

WebApi2 project reads from web.config in `WebApiConfig` class by using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filename"]`. So I created a `app.config` in my unit test project with same config item, I also set the property to `Copy Always` to make sure it will be copied to the same folder where test DLL resides.

When I run the unit test locally in Visual Studio 2015, it is great. But when I run the test on Jenkins server it failed. From the exception message on Jenkins server it is obvious that the code reading config file gets the blank data.

I browsed to the Jenkins server workplace and I do see 2 files `app.config` and `mytest.dll.config` are there. So it is obviously the file has been copied properly. But reading config still failed.

Anyone might have some clue?

Comment: Are you using any path variables from the config? Could be some path issues? If you share the config. it will be easy to in point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is to enable `NonIsloation` mode in jenkins.